# How does the first argument of the following `t.test()` work? How can it be a numeric vector of data values?

Tags: r

for the built-in matrix `ToothGrowth` :

```
  tooth.1mg <- subset(ToothGrowth,dose==1)

   tt <- t.test(len~supp,tooth.1mg,alternative="two.sided",
   +             var.equal=FALSE,conf.level=0.95)
```

How `len~supp` works ? what does the symbol `~` indicate ?

why can't i write `supp~len`
?

Answer (score 1):

[This is what it does](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Two-sample_T.C2.A02_test) with a formula interface. Also see `?t.test`.

Should be clear from that and the error message why `supp~len` can't work - the `rhs` of the formula is supposed to be a categorical variable, i.e. a `factor`, with precisely two categories (and `lhs` are the values in each category).